# Find total description and copy paste values 4 rows down

Tags: excel, vba

Does anyone know what other command I need to use to copy the row label "Total WI Expenses" down 4 rows below?

The following code will find the "Total WI Expenses" and copy it to a range, however, I just want to find the total and copy the data to the 4 rows down. They need to be copied and pasted as values.

```
Sub Test()
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Set ws = ActiveSheet 
  Dim rw As Long, Cell As Range
  For Each Cell In ActiveSheet.Range("B:B")
    If Cell.Value = "Total WI Expenses" Then
      Cell.EntireRow.copy
      Range("A71").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)
      Application.CutCopyMode = False
    End If
  Next
End Sub
```

I sincerely appreciate your assistance.

Comment: It works perfectly!! You are super hero!!! Thank you!!!

Comment: Did you mean my answer? The you should comment below it and mark it as usable :)

Comment: @AlexD: It is a custom on SO to accept helpful answers by clicking on the green arrow next to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of running a `For` loop over the whole(!) column you may check first, if something is in the column, and then `.Find` the wanted value. If you found a result, then you may use it's row number.

Instead of Copy/Paste you may just assign the `Range.Value` to get the values without formatting.

This code copies the whole row's values four rows below.

```
Sub Test()
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim c As Range

    Set ws = ActiveSheet
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Columns(2)) > 0 Then
        Set c = ws.Columns(2).Find( _
            What:="Total WI Expenses", _
            After:=ws.Cells(1, 2), _
            SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlNext)
        If Not c Is Nothing Then
            ws.Rows(c.Row + 4).Value = ws.Rows(c.Row).Value
        End If
        Set c = Nothing
    End If
    Set ws = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: FYI Thank you,I'm new to this site.  This my second time asking questions everyone has been very nice. I sincerely appreciate everyone’s support.

Comment: Hello, I want to thank you for providing the code. If I need additional values other then the total would I be able to use the same command what = “ my value “?

Comment: Of course, the `Range.Find` searches the `What`. Look here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find

Comment: I tried modfing the code but is not work, can you please give me a helping hand?

Comment: Basically I was trying to find these rows and copy the data to sheet 2  Total Revenue:
Net Revenue to the WI Owners
Total WI Expenses
Average $ per BBL

Comment: I think that your initial question is answered, but you've got a new code-problem now, so please consider asking a new question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask)